# How to scroll to bottom of ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am using a Winforms ListBox as a small list of events, and want to populate it so that the last event (bottom) is visible. The `SelectionMode` is set to none. The user can scroll the list but I would prefer it start out scrolled to the end.

Looking at the lack of support for things like `ScrollIntoView`, `EnsureVisible`, I am assuming I will need to create a custom control that inherits from ListBox; however I'm not sure what to do from there.

Some pointers?

Comment: Did the normal `listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;` not work for you?

Comment: That works when `SelectionMode` is not set to `None`. I need to prevent selecting items in this particular list (to avoid user confusion).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I believe you can do that easily by setting the [`TopIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex.aspx) property appropriately.

For example:

```
int visibleItems = listBox.ClientSize.Height / listBox.ItemHeight;
listBox.TopIndex = Math.Max(listBox.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0);
```

Comment: +1 A bit convoluted, but that's certainly not your fault! Thanks for the solution and example.

Comment: It seems to work fine if you just set `TopIndex` to the last item instead of worrying about which should really be at the top, e.g. `listBox.TopIndex = listBox.Items.Count - 1;`

Answer (score 83):

**Scroll to the bottom:**

`listbox.TopIndex = listbox.Items.Count - 1;`

**Scroll to the bottom, and select the last item:**

`listbox.SelectedIndex = listbox.Items.Count - 1;`

Comment: I prefer this solution, much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Best solution.,

Comment: My ListBox doesn't have a `TopIndex` property (no idea why) and setting `SelectedIndex` doesn't scroll to the selection.

Comment: @Malcolm Are you using winforms?

Comment: @markf78 WPF, my bad. That'll teach me to gloss over question tags >_<

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up with for WPF (.Net Framework 4.6.1):

```
Scroll.ToBottom(listBox);
```

Using the following utility class:

```
public partial class Scroll
{
    private static ScrollViewer FindViewer(DependencyObject root)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>(new[] { root });

        do
        {
            var item = queue.Dequeue();
            if (item is ScrollViewer) { return (ScrollViewer)item; }
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(item);
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { queue.Enqueue(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, i)); }
        } while (queue.Count > 0);

        return null;
    }

    public static void ToBottom(ListBox listBox)
    {
        var scrollViewer = FindViewer(listBox);

        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += (o, args) =>
            {
                if (args.ExtentHeightChange > 0) { scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom(); }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question was tagged WinForms.

Comment: @LarsTech That is an excellent point, but my answer may help a few WPF people, yes?

Comment: Why not an extension method instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a winforms listbox that "sticks to bottom when at bottom" you can:

```
int visibleItems = lb.ClientSize.Height / lb.ItemHeight;
if (lb.Items.Count > lb && lb.TopIndex > lb.Items.Count - visibleItems - 2)
  lb.TopIndex = lb.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1;
```

When scrolled to bottom, new items will cause it to scroll down to show them, but if you scroll up a bit, then it ceases its "jump to bottom" behavior yso you can carry on looking at what you scrolled up to see