# Scroll to top and bottom on listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have `ListBox` named **lstFiles** that display file names of images, then when selected from the listbox, from either mouse or keyboard.

The image will then be shown within a `PictureBox` **pictureBox1**, but I am having trouble trying to make the `ListBox` go back to the top after the last entry has been listed, If you selected the down arrow on the keyboard on the last entry, and have the top entry selected, I want the same going to the bottom entry when you hit the up arrow key on the first entry.

I have tried and can't get it to work within the listbox

**I have three joint listboxes to display the system drive, folders and its content**

```
private void lstDrive_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstFolders.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            DriveInfo drive = (DriveInfo)lstDrive.SelectedItem;

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in drive.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
                lstFolders.Items.Add(dirInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void lstFolders_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstFiles.Items.Clear();

        DirectoryInfo dir = (DirectoryInfo)lstFolders.SelectedItem;

        foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
            lstFiles.Items.Add(fi);
    }

    private void lstFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)lstFiles.SelectedItem).FullName);

        //I have tried this, but it makes the selected cursor go straight to the bottom file//
        lstFiles.SelectedIndex = lstFiles.Items.Count - 1;

        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796747/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-of-listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this by handling the `ListBox KeyUp` event. Try this :

```
    private int lastIndex = 0;

    private void listBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == lastIndex)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }                

        }

        lastIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    }
```